# Placeholder para input type date

Tags: javascript, html, css, date

Necesito arreglar mi aplicación.
Estoy armando un formulario de inscripción para una escuela de baile.

La cuestión es que pongo una parte en la que pido la fecha de nacimiento de la siguiente manera:

```
<label for="nac" class="sr-only">Fecha de Nacimiento</label>
<input onfocus="(this.type='date')" class="form-control" placeholder="Fecha de nacimiento" id="nac" name="nac">
```

En los navegadores de la pc se ve bien, el tema es en los celulares, el input no funciona correctamente.

Se ve de la siguiente manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Además, no abre ninguna posibilidad de añadir las fechas, y colocar las correspondientes.

Aclaro además que estoy usando bootstrap para el diseño.

Comment: Probé el código que adjuntaste y veo que el responsive del input date funciona correctamente, no logre hacer que aparezca el error que dices. Podrías por favor adjuntar mas codigo que usas en tu aplicacion? de todos modos te dejo este enlace https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp que habla sobre el @media, la cual es una regla de css que sirve para aplicar ciertos estilos en los diferentes tamaños de la pantalla, tal vez te ayude a solucionarlo. Saludos.

Comment: @John el OP aclara que usa Bootstrap, sobra que le recomiendes `@media`.